# Duplicate subdomains and SEO

Tags: seo, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

I have two subdomains for the same website. One has quite a high page rank, the other does not register. Is there anything that I need to think about in regards of SEO in this scenario?

EDIT:

Example: `blog.example.com` and `drupal.example.com` are two aliases for the same content. The first has a very high page rank, the second has none.

Comment: What you mean under 2 duplicate domains, can you explain it a little further and give a link(s)?

Comment: yes can you rephrase this and provide `example.com` specifics of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid to spawn the same website on multiple domains.

The best things you can do is pick one domain, and make it the default one. Update all the links to reflect the choice.
Then, configure a 301 redirect for each page on all the other domains to the default one.

Using a server configuration or a script, it's really easy to setup the redirect.
It's just a matter of a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same content on two subdomains then you have duplicate content. One will be filtered out as a result. That seems to explain your issues if I am understanding your question properly. If not update your questions so we can better answer it for you.

Edit:

If you mean you have two subdomains with different content then one will not affect the other. All pages are judged on their own merit so if your pages in one subdomain do not rank well it may be because they do not deserve to rank well (yet). It may also be something causing them to not be reachable by the search engines. Google webmaster tools will tall you if that is the case.